# Why php is not running following order of commands in sequence?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I wrote this code to check the live sequence in which actual code runs in php

```
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    echo 'Begin ...<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    echo "Hello<br />";
    flush();    
    ob_flush();
    sleep(5);
```

The expected output should be in this order :
1. Begin
2. Hello
3. sleep(5)

But the order in which they are actually executed is :
1.Begin
2.sleep(5)
3.Hello
If php is really sequential then it should follow the sequence given then why this difference ? And if i want to execute commands strictly in the sequence then what is the procedure as I need it for updating progress bar width.

You can check this behaviour by commenting the sleep function it won't wait between Begin and Hello also.
Iam using codeigniter framework.

Comment: I believe CI uses output buffering. It also uses output compression, if enabled. These two things will interfere with flushing content.

Comment: Thanks but ouput compression was disabled when i took the above observation, yes but maybe it schedules the second echo and then calls sleep how to change this behavior i want this in exact sequence ?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases flushing alone is not enough, the Browser needs at least I think it was 256kb of data, in some browsers at least but it depends and changes, before it SHOWS the flush, so it is fluesh but you do not see the result, try something like

```
echo "Hello<br />";
str_repeat(" ",256);
```

I know it is too much but it should work, then you should see what you expect

you can play with the number if it is not what you expect, as I said it also depends on the used browser :D

Comment: Thanks but if it is so then   
echo 'Hello ...<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();

    echo "World<br />";
    flush();    
    ob_flush(); is flushing live even though its not 256Kb

Comment: not really.. in your first flush you also got the headers ;)